# ajax issue for form element on hook_form_alter in drupal 7

Tags: ajax, forms

```
function clicktell_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //print_r($form);
  if($form_id == 'create_rental_node_form') {
    $form['tax_form'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="tax-form">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',

    );
    // Add Term button
    $form['test_btn'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Add term'),
      '#name' => 'addform',
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
      //'#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'wrapper' => 'tax-form',
        'callback' => 'clicktell_addterm_form',
        'method' => 'replace', // this is important without this if else condition for ajax will not work.
        'effect' => 'fade',
      )
    );

    $form['#validate'] = array();
    //$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array();

//  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array(
//    'callback' => 'clicktell_node_create_callback',
//  );


    return $form;
  }

}
function clicktell_addterm_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // not being specific with return form value for example
    //print_r($form_state);exit;
  $form['test_btn']['#value'] = 'New value';;
  return $form;
}`enter code here`
```

Ajax is not working. every time pages refreshes don't know how to use ajax in form alter. please help me.

Comment: Maybe this example could help - https://gist.github.com/pascalduez/1517513

Comment: I already tried this example code this working fine. but in my case I am using this on hook_form_alter where it is not working.

Comment: So if we use hook_form_alter(), we need a different approach for making an AJAX request in Drupal?